# Should I continue pursuing full-time employment at a firm after one bad experience (but many good experiences)?

Tags: management

I am an employee on a six month contract with a firm of around 60 employees in the western US. My manager reports directly to the CEO, who owns the company. When I took the job, the expectation was that after the initial contract, there may be more part time work.

Towards the end of the contract, I asked to interview for a full time position and my manager said that both him and the CEO were very interested.

After several reminders, my manager arranged an interview with him (him only and not the CEO) and verbally assured me that I was in, and the question was more of how much to pay me.

Later that week, I received a written offer from another company for part-time work, and told my manager about it. My manager responded by saying that she would start writing the job description for my full-time role. After a few days, I asked my manager for a rough date for when I could expect a written offer, and she said she would respond with a firm date by the next day. The next day came and went. Over the next few days, I sent one reminder to my manager each day, which she ignored (I work remotely).

Finally, two days before my other written offer expired, I directly contacted the CEO asking about the full time role, explaining very politely that my manager is doing all she can, but was overloaded. The CEO responded by saying he would need to connect with my manager, and he couldn't promise anything by the deadline. I then asked the other firm for an extension, and they gave a very generous extension.

Shortly after I contacted the CEO, the manager gave me a call, apologizing for the delay. After I told the manager I obtained an extension, she said she would talk with the CEO tomorrow and get an offer a few days in advance of the new deadline. Tomorrow came and went, and I sent a reminder daily, my manager did not reply to my messages. The only time I managed to get a response about my hiring was during our Skype meetings, when she said she didn't manage to talk to the CEO but would be talking to the CEO later that day, and I would be the first thing that would be discussed. But nothing materialized.

Four days later, I contacted the CEO a second time. Shortly after this, my manager gave me a call, saying that I should proceed with the other offer.

The next day, the CEO unexpectedly joined a routine call with my manager. The CEO told me that I had pushed the issue too hard, and my manager told me that she mentioned before that I might not be able to meet my timeline. Both of them said that they were otherwise very satisfied with me. I personally am generally very happy with the company, except for this incident. The CEO verbally said that after my contract we should continue to work together with me in a limited role, and subsequently moving up to a full time position as the company expanded.

However, there were some troubling signs. During the phone call, nothing in our conversation indicated that my manager discussed my full-time employment with the CEO before I had contacted the CEO. In fact, the CEO said that my manager had told him (the CEO) that she (the manager) did not think I should have a full-time role now, only sometime in the future.

Very shortly, I'll be working part time for my new firm.

I am uncertain about whether I should continue to work with the firm if they extend a part-time employment offer, and if so, whether I should eventually seek full-time employment with them.

If I decide to continue to seek full time employment in the future with my current firm, how should I continue with this?

Besides this incident, the rest of my experiences have been very good and I like the firm a lot. The problem is that this incident is leaving a very sour taste.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "how to behave?" What options do you have to choose from?

Comment: You had an offer from another company, so I would think that you will get another offer again, even more so if you actively search. When you do, make sure you get a good salary, sign the contract, then give notice.

Comment: You should accept the other offer. You also did badly telling them you had an extension of the deadline. They are either waiting to see if you stick with them, or do not want you to have a position of leverage when proposing you a small salary. In the worst case scenario, they just do not have the face to tell you no.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the situation correctly, it looks as though you've been offered a permanent role, but the company has been half-hearted in putting that offer into actual words.

It's difficult to know whether your manager has either been too busy, too undecided, or simply not committed enough to give you the offer.  However, if they really did want you, they would have been more committed to giving you a concrete offer.

I've done this myself at my current employer, where I started as a contractor.  I was offered a chance for a full-time role, I accepted, we negotiated a salary, and I was hired.  It was clear and unambiguous.

So you have an external offer.  I'd be tempted to take up that offer, based on the fact that you can't pay bills with promises.

For your current gig, you just need to part ways with:

> Sorry this didn't work out.  I really enjoyed working with you guys and hope to see you again in the future.

In taking an external role, you're not burning your bridges with your current employer - both sides know that there's been a breakdown in expectations and communications.  It might be that you clearly indicating that you're taking an external offer might clear some cogs and set something firmly in motion here.

The bottom line is that you need to take control of what's going on, you can't really hang around waiting on promises and pushing at something that doesn't really want to move (right now).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never, under any circumstances trash talk a previous employer.  It may feel good, and you may even feel justified because the employer treated you like dirt, but in my experience, it will only come back to bite you. Secondly, it is very unprofessional to trash talk and demonstrates immaturity.

You should mention, instead, only the positive, preferably, quantifiable experiences that resulted in some kind of acquired skill set that you can then utilize elsewhere, but don't go into a lengthy explanation of what led to the break up. If pressed as to why you left, then keep it simple. State the facts. You left because you agreed to disagree with the previous employer on what constituted transparency with regard to your job vs. not. A reasonable employer will accept this answer while the unscrupulous ones will want you to painstakingly explain, in which case, that will be your red flag.  Personally, I would avoid working for any org that had a problem with transparency as it pertains to how the employees are treated.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It is a good answer, but to a different question.

Comment: @Roland since you continue to stalk me on this forum posing completely irrelevant and immaterial, presumably, rhetorical questions, I'm going to have to tell you that I refuse to pay the troll toll for crossing the bridge.  But you just keep on keepin' on, honey.  You are probably impressing your parents, at least!

Comment: It's always a pleasure to see such a mature reaction to constructive feedback.